# Delete rows that sum with two columns up to a certain value in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have following table:

```
filename    w   POS ID  b   c   d   h 
766_V   13  73711300    rs35852582  0.03046218  0.49789916  0   0.0987395   
75_S    13  73711300    rs35852582  0.03046218  0.49789916  0.09821429  0.00052521  
81_Y    13  73711300    rs35852582  0.03046218  0.49789916  0.1968908   0.00105042   
2151_L  13  73711300    rs35852582  0.03046218  0.49789916  0.09768908  0.00105042       
2051_K  13  73711300    rs35852582  0.03046218  0.49789916  0.3105042   0.09768908   
921_V   13  73711300    rs35852582  0.03046218  0.49789916  0.00105042  0.09768908       
533_D   13  73711300    rs35852582  0.03046218  0.49789916  0.00105042  0.09768908       
330_M   13  73711300    rs35852582  0.03046218  0.49789916  0.00105042  0.09768908       
2954_A  13  73711300    rs35852582  0.03046218  0.49789916  0.00105042  0.09768908
```

I would like to delete rows that do not sum up to 0.2 in the columns `b` and `d`. So in the end I would like to have only rows that have a sum in the columns `5` and `7` of `>=0.2`. The resulting table table:

```
filename    w   POS ID  b   c   d   h 
81_Y    13  73711300    rs35852582  0.03046218  0.49789916  0.1968908   0.00105042    
2051_K  13  73711300    rs35852582  0.03046218  0.49789916  0.3105042   0.09768908
```

I tried this code, but I couldnt find a way to specify two specific columns:

```
awk 'NR>1 {sum=0; for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) { sum+= $i } if (sum > 0.2) print}' file.txt
```

Comment: So output records where `$5+$7>=0.02`? Every value in `$5` is already `>=0.02`. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Or do you separately need to figure out which columns have which header? There's a duplicate for that, too.

Comment: Hi, yes, it doesn't matter, if one column is already `>=0.02`. I want that the sum between them is `>=0.02`.

Comment: If you already know the number of the columns to sum (in this case `b=$5` and `d=$7`): `awk 'NR==1 ||  (NR>1 && ($5 + $7 > 0.2))' file.txt`

Comment: Sorry, I edit the question, I meant 0.2 and not 0.02.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane 'print if $. == 1 || ($F[4] + $F[6]) > 0.02;' file.txt > out.txt
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'/\t/'` : Split into `@F` on TAB, rather than on whitespace.

`$.` : line number (check if it is 1, that is, if it is the header line, and then print it).
`$F[4]` : The 5th column (the fields of the array `@F` are 0-indexed).

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)